# Find file and line of 'unexpectedly found nil'

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I updated to Xcode 8.3.3 and updated my OS, a bunch of pods, and so on.  Now when I crash on `unexpectedly found nil` it takes me to a stack trace with it stopped on 'exc_breakpoint' (see screen shot).  I have no breakpoints set.

I can't effectively troubleshoot these 'nil' errors because I don't know where they're occurring in my project (I can do it slowly by using a back trace and trying to sort through the messages, but this is way slower than if it just landed me on the right line like it used to do.)

Do I have some setting turned on by accident?  Is this a bug?  How can I get Xcode to go straight to the line of the nil crash?

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: try adding a exception break point..

Comment: @Frankie , I think you are running in device. Try with simulator...

Comment: Type `bt` in the debugger window to get the backtrace, then look through to see the last place it was in your code.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, I'm also faced this issues in  my project. I just used to solve this by setting **breakpoint** in my code and I run manually line by line. Finally it will shows the nil value passing line.

If I faced crash issue while clicking **any action button** i will set breakpoint and run it line by line.

else if I faced crash issue while **page loading**. I will set breakpoint in `viewdidload` & `viewdidappear`

else I will set breakpoint in **functions**.

or try to use exception breakpoint

### [image]

[image]

Through this above method I will solve crash issue in my project.